# Database independency using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate for ORM in my Java application. I want to write custom queries combining multiple tables and using DB functions like `sum(salary)`. 
I also want to support multiple databases without writing the SQLs again and again for each database. The approach currently followed
is having Stored Procedures specific to each DB (`Oracle`, `MySQL` etc) and whichever we want to support, we change the configuration file in the application.
What I am looking for is a solution very generic so that I need not write Stored Procedures or SQLs for every new functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep it portable, you'll need to do it all with HQL.

There's no reason that you couldn't do multi-table joins and aggregate functions in HQL, you just need to limit yourself to the ones it supports.

Once you start doing database-vendor specific things, you are no longer database independent, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

A perfect suite is HIbernate Criterias

> Hibernate provides alternate ways of manipulating objects and in turn data available in RDBMS tables. One of the methods is Criteria API which allows you to build up a criteria query object programmatically where you can apply filtration rules and logical conditions.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm